# How do I add cross-cutting information to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging events?

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core-2.0, seq

I'm trying to set up a basic prototype of client-server applications, both using ASP.NET Core 2.0. As part of this, I'm sending diagnostic information to Seq. In the `Startup` class for each application, I'm using [`Seq.Extensions.Logging`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Seq.Extensions.Logging/) and configuring the Seq sinks as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug)
            .AddSeq();
    });
```

This works; all the events appear in Seq. However, it's not possible to easily distinguish which application any specific event is from.

In the past, using Serilog, I have been able to add propertes to the logger which are included in every event. Typically I would add the name of the application and the host it is running on as a pair of additional properties:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithMachineName()
    // ...other configuration...
    .CreateLogger();
```

Is there a way to configure the Microsoft logging extensions to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for you.

1. Use built-in `Seq` feature.

For `Seq`, it provides [API Keys](https://docs.getseq.net/docs/api-keys) which is used to identity the client application. You could add the `Applied properties` with the specific name like your project name, and configure the api key by

```
            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.AddSeq(Configuration.GetSection("Seq"));
        });
```

Or

```
            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {                
            loggingBuilder.AddSeq("http://xxx:5341", apiKey: "K5HzACIfiQxr67CKlvUj");
        });
```

2. Use `Serilog` to configure the output template like

   ```
           var output = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message} {ActionName} {UserName} {NewLine}{Exception} {MachineName}";

       Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .Enrich.FromLogContext() // Populates a 'User' property on every log entry
              .Enrich.WithProperty("MachineName", Environment.MachineName) //new field
              .WriteTo.RollingFile("Logs/app-{Date}.txt", outputTemplate: output)
              .WriteTo.Seq("http://xxx:5341",apiKey: "K5HzACIfiQxr67CKlvUj")
              .CreateLogger();
       loggerFactory
           //.AddFile("Logs/app-{Date}.txt")
           .AddSerilog();
   ```